# How do I enter supervisor mode on the ARM Cortex m4 to disable interrupts?

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m

Im trying to find out how I can disable and enable interrupts on the STM32L4x6RG Nucleo?

After a bit of googling I found the macros __disble_irq() and __enable_irq() but I'm not convinced these are disabling interrupts.

After more investigation it seems that the cpsid instruction this macro maps to only has effect when it runs in supervisor context. So the question becomes how do I move to supervisor mode to disable interrupts and back again??

Comment: why not? What part of the documentation does make you unsure. Those macros are just the part of the CMSIS - I advise to read the documentation on the ARM site instead of being "convinced" or not.

Comment: PS googling when you try to do something with ARM uC is not the very best way. Internet is full of myths - better read the official documentation which is quite good.

Comment: You need to make an SVC call to enter privileged mode. In the SVC handler you can then change to privileged mode by changing bit 0 of the control register. Look it up, there is plenty on the web about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processor boots in privileged mode so unless you are running your application on top of an operating system or have switched to unprivileged mode yourself you should already be in privileged mode. If you are running you application on top of an OS you should use its services to handle interrupts and if no such service exists you should leave the interrupts alone.

If you have switched to unprivileged-mode yourself, you can use the `svc` instruction to trigger an svc-exception and the handler for the exception executes in privileged mode.

Comment: Im not using an operating system, I am using the Low-level (LL) library calls.  So presumably the processor is in privileged mode unless the ST boot code sets it to unprivileged?

Comment: @err There is no "ST boot code" that would set the processor to unprivileged mode. You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

> I found the macros __disble_irq() and __enable_irq() but I'm not
>   convinced these are disabling interrupts.

They do, unless you (or the OS you are using) explicitly leave [privileged mode](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDIGFCA.html) with the [`MSR control, Rn`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBIBGJ.html#BABIFGGB) instruction, or the `__set_CONTROL()` function, which does the same.

> So the question becomes how do I move to supervisor mode to disable
>   interrupts and back again??

The processor is in privileged mode after reset, and stays in it unless you tell it otherwise. It also enters privileged mode temporarily when executing an exception handler.

You can use the [`SVC` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABBHFJE.html) to call the SVC exception handler from user code, and run some code in privileged mode. There is a problem though, that the SVC handler invocation would be blocked too by `__disable_irq()`, so there would be no way to reenable them afterwards. Instead of `__disable_irq()`, you can adjust the [`BASEPRI` register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBIBGJ.html#BABHCGDA) to selectively disable lower priority interrupts, and set SVC priority higher so that it would not be blocked.